# I Cannot Update A Table in Ms Access with C#. No Error Message

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to update a table in Ms Access whenever I click save button in C#. So, whenever I add a new value into the [Checkin] table, the [kamar] table will update itself. But, [kamar] table doesn't want to update. There is no error message.
Here is my code:

```
 private void simpan()
    {
        string noreg = noregBox.Text;
        string noktp = noktpCBox.Text;
        string nokamar = nokamarCBox.Text;
        string tglCheckin = txttanggalCheckin.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        decimal dp = Convert.ToDecimal(dpBox.Text);
        if (nokamar.Equals("") || noreg.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data tidak boleh kosong");
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            cmdCheckin = new OleDbCommand("insert into Checkin (no_reg_in,tgl_checkin,no_ktp,no_kamar,dp_kamar) values ('" + noreg + "', '" + tglCheckin + "', '" + noktp + "', '" + nokamar + "',  '" + dp + "')", cn);
            cmdCheckin.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil disimpan");
            nokamarCBox.Text = "";
            noktpCBox.Text = "";
            namatamuBox.Clear();
            jktamuCBox.Text = "";
            telptamuBox.Clear();
            alamatBox.Clear();
            kelaskamarBox.Clear();
            biayaBox.Clear();
            dpBox.Clear();
            muat();
        }
        catch (OleDbException error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(error));
            return;
        }
    }

private void perbarui()
    {
        string nokamar = nokamarCBox.Text;
        string kelas = kelaskamarBox.Text;

        try
        {
            cmdCheckin = new OleDbCommand("update kamar set status = 0 where no_kamar = '" + nokamar + "'", cn);
            cmdCheckin.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dtCheckin.Clear();
            daCheckin.Fill(dtCheckin);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data gagal diubah, error" + err);
        }
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        simpan();
        perbarui();
        muat();
    }
```

button2 is save button. Thank you. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you set:

```
nokamarCBox.Text = "";
```

Then:

```
string nokamar = nokamarCBox.Text;
```

Thus, no nokamar is to update.